How to manage version compatibility between microservices and external packages in NestJS?
We have several microservices running on different versions of NestJS—specifically versions 8, 9, and 10. Additionally, we use external modules, such as an Auth module, which is located in a separate npm package. This module includes various guards and services for user authentication. The external modules are built for a specific NestJS version, in our case, version 8.
The problem we're facing is that the external module based on NestJS 8 is not compatible with our microservices running on NestJS 10. However, upgrading the external module to NestJS 10 would break compatibility with the microservices still on version 8.
Given that we're unable to upgrade all microservices at once, do you have any recommendations or approaches for handling this situation while maintaining the current state of our microservices? Is there perhaps a way to build external guards/services that are compatible with different NestJS versions? Or the only wat is to duplicate these external modules?
Thank you!

I am not sure I follow, it sounds like you are describing an impossible state, in which neither your version 10 nor version 8 microservices can coexist using the Auth module. So how is this possible right now?
You say you have instances running version 10. Which auth do they use then?

That's what we are trying to solve. For now, microservices with Nest 10 have duplicated code from the external auth module. However duplication of code is very tedious. Basically, we have to put duplicate of auth guards in such services. That's why I am curious how people manage such compatibility issues

You are halfway there then - take your "duplicate" version-10 compatible code, make a fork of your auth library.
Then point all your version 10 instances to build with that, as well as your version 8 services, which you can now update to NestJs 10, pointing to your new forked npm package.
Basically just versioning, that's how people manage compatibility
